# Change content within a dropdown On Select

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I have a page in which the user needs to select a product based on drop down filtering. Consider four drop downs Category--> SubCategory-->Product---> Variant. Its not so user friendly when the user has to select value from each drop down to get the final variant. So I need to select all the values with a subnavigation within a single drop down. You can view what I mean in this link -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMoQX.gif
Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Don't you think a Tree View control is the better choice here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can split in three columns and using radio button group in each column to select category or product, filtering in each column[image]